# fckeditor upload problem

Tags: asp.net, fckeditor, uploading

I am trying to use the upload feature in FckEditor but when I choose the file and press upload I get "Upload in progress please wait" but nothing happened , knowing that I can create new folder and brows the existed files which in the image directory. 

 
I've edited the configuration sittings to the target directory and set the write and modify permissions .

```
        // SECURITY: You must explicitly enable this "connector". (Set it to "true").
    Enabled = CheckAuthentication();

    // URL path to user files.
    UserFilesPath = "/Files/";

    // The connector tries to resolve the above UserFilesPath automatically.
    // Use the following setting it you prefer to explicitely specify the
    // absolute path. Examples: 'C:\\MySite\\userfiles\\' or '/root/mysite/userfiles/'.
    // Attention: The above 'UserFilesPath' URL must point to the same directory.
    UserFilesAbsolutePath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/");
```